# MATLAB - Using for loops find all the combinations of x^2 + y

Tags: matlab, loops

I have two for loops like this:

```
for x = 1:1:15
    for y = 1:1:15
        values(x,y) = x^2 + y
    end
end
```

This allows me to calculate x^2 + y for every combination of x and y if they are integers.

However, what if I want to calculate x^2 + y for decimals as well?

So something like this:

```
for x = 0:0.1:15
    for y = 0:0.1:15
        ????? = x^2 + y
    end
end
```

Could anyone help me find a method that can calculate all the possibilities of x^2 + y if x and y are decimals so cannot be used as index references anymore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
[x y] = ndgrid(0:0.1:15);
values = x.^2 + y;
```

Issues with the other answers:

1. @inigo's answer will change the order of `x` and `y` compared to your initial example (by using `meshgrid` rather than `ndgrid`.
2. @NominSim's answer has to go to extra effort get `d_x` from `x`
3. @mecid's answer has to count columns and rows separately (also there is no ++ operator in MATLAB). If I was to go down @mecid's route I would use the following.

> ```
> x = 0:.1:15;
> y = 0:.1:15;
> values = zeros(numel(x),numel(y));
> for xnum = 1:numel(x)
>     for ynum = 1:numel(y)
>         values(xnum,ynum) = x(xnum)^2 + y(ynum);
>     end
> end
> ```

Since it generated some discussion, from the documentation (within MATLAB, not in the online documentation) on the difference between `meshgrid` and `ndgrid`:

`meshgrid` is like `ndgrid` except that the order of the first two input and output arguments are switched (i.e., `[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(x,y,z)` produces the same result as `[Y,X,Z] = ndgrid(y,x,z)`) ... `meshgrid` is also limited to 2D or 3D.

Comment: +1 I like the use of `ndgrid` rather than `meshgrid`. I've run into the cartesian vs. row/col problem several times. Here is a nice link explaining the difference between `ndgrid` and `meshgrid`: http://www.mathworks.com.au/support/solutions/en/data/1-1AOGG/index.html?product=SL&solution=1-1AOGG

Comment: Note that my comments on @inigo's answer are out of date since, after my answer, he changed from `[x y] = meshgrid` to `[y x] = meshgrid` which is indeed the same as `[x y] = ndgrid`.

Answer (score 5):

use [meshgrid](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html), matlab's built in rectangular grid in 2-D and there's no need to loop!

```
[y x]=meshgrid(0:0.1:15)
values=x.^2+y
```

to visualize this:

```
imagesc(values);
title('values=x^2+y'); axis square
xlabel('x'); ylabel('y'); colorbar;
axis xy;
set(gca,'XTick',1:10:151,'YTick',1:10:151);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',0:1:15,'YTickLabel',0:1:15);
```

[image]

**EDIT:**
`mdgrid` is also fine the only thing to note is that `[y x]=meshgrid...` is the same  `[x y]=ndgird...`

Comment: +1 Simple, straight forward answer. (I liked the use of the visualisation too... where did that go?)

Comment: Simple and good answer. I prefer `axis xy` to the more complex `set(gca,'ydir', 'normal')`. Shorter...

Comment: thanks for the comment, I agree the `axis xy` is shorter and better. I'll edit that in...

Answer (score 2):

```
for x =1:0.1:15
  for y=1:0.1:15
    values(x*10-10, y*10-10) =x^2+y;
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not loop on integers from 1 to 151 then calculate the decimal to be used? Then you can still use index references.

i.e.

```
for x = 1:1:151
    for y = 1:1:151
        d_x = x / 10.0 - 0.1
        d_y = y / 10.0 - 0.1
        values(x,y) = d_x^2 + d_y
    end
end
```

(Forgive me if my syntax is slightly off, haven't used MATLAB in a while).